# python improving word game

Tags: python

Im working on a word game. The purpose for the user is to guess a 5 letter word in 5 attempts. The user can know the first letter. And if he doesn't get the word correct, but if he has a letter in the correct place he gets to know this.

This is my code:

```
  import random
list_of_words = ["apple","table", "words", "beers", "plural", "hands"]
word = random.choice(list_of_words)

attempts = 5

for attempt in range(attempts):
    if attempt == 0:
        tempList = list(word[0] + ("." * 4))
        print("The first letter of the word we are looking for: %s" % "".join(tempList))

    answer = raw_input("What is the word we are looking for?:")
    if len(answer) != 5:
        print ('Please enter a 5 letter word')

    Else:
        if answer != word:
            wordlist = list(word)
            answerlist = list(answer)
            for i in range(min(len(wordlist), len(answerlist))):
                if wordlist[i] == answerlist[i]:
                    tempList[i] = wordlist[i]
            print(tempList)

        else:
            print("correct, you have guessed the word in:", attempt, "attempts")

if answer != word:
    print("Sorry maximum number of tries, the word is: %s" % word)
```

I have two questions about this code:

The first one is a small problem: If the user gives a 6 or 4 letter word it will still print the word. While I'd rather have it that the word is just ignored and the attempt isnt used..

If a letter is given correct (and also the first letter) it doesnt become a standard part of the feedback. Trying to get this with temp but of yet its not working great.

Any suggestions to clean up my code are also appreciated!

Thanks for your attention

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I made some changes in your code, now it's working according to your specification. I also wrote a couple of explaining comments in it:

```
import random

list_of_words = ["apple", "table", "words", "beers", "plural", "hands"]
word = random.choice(list_of_words)

# changed the loop to a 'while', because i don't want to count the invalid length answers
# and wanted to exit the loop, when the user guessed correctly
attempts = 5
attempt = 0
correct = False
while attempt < attempts and not correct:
    if attempt == 0:
        # i stored a working copy of the initial hint (ex: "w....")
        # i'll use this to store the previously correctrly guessed letters
        tempList = list(word[0] + ("." * 4))
        print("The first letter of the word we are looking for: %s" % "".join(tempList))

    answer = raw_input("What is the word we are looking for?:")
    if len(answer) != 5:
        print("Please enter a 5 letter word")
    else:
        if answer != word:
            # i simplified this loop to comparing the wordlist and answerlist and update templist accordingly
            wordlist = list(word)
            answerlist = list(answer)
            for i in range(min(len(wordlist), len(answerlist))):
                if wordlist[i] == answerlist[i]:
                    tempList[i] = wordlist[i]
            print(tempList)
        else:
            correct = True
            print("Correct, you have guessed the word in %s attempts" % (attempt + 1))
        attempt += 1

if answer != word:
    # also i used string formatting on your prints, so is prints as a string, and not as a tuple.
    print("Sorry maximum number of tries, the word is: %s" % word)
```

Comment: @ zord. Wow this is great man, many thanks! My first version also contained a 'while' but changed it later on. Guess in the end 'while' works better. Thanks, I appreciate it! Cheers

Answer (score 1):

There are several problems with the code.

Just 1 for now.   I notice in the sample output you are entering five letter words (beeds and bread) and it still prints out `Please enter a 5 letter word`.

These two lines:

```
if len(answer) != 4:
    print ('Please enter a 5 letter word')
```

Surely this should be:

```
if len(answer) != 5:
    print ('Please enter a 5 letter word')
    continue
```

This would catch an invalid input and go round the loop again.

Answer (score 1):

Answering your specific questions:

1. You will need to have a `for` loop around your `input`, keeping the user in that loop until they enter a word of appropriate length
2. If you move guessed letters to the correct places, it is trivial to win by guessing `"abcde"` then `"fghij"`, etc. You need to think carefully about what your rules will be; you could have a separate list of "letters in the guess that are in the answer but in the wrong place" and show the user this.
3. To keep the display version with all previously-guessed characters, keep a list of the display characters: `display = ["." for letter in answer]`, and update this as you go.

Other problems you have:

1. Too much hard-coding of word length (especially as `len("plural") != 5`); you should rewrite your code to *use* the length of the word (this makes it more flexible).
2. You only tell the user they've won if they guess the whole answer. What if they get to it with overlapping letters? You could test as `if all(letter != "." for letter in display):` to see if they have got to the answer that way.
3. Your list comprehension `[i for i in answer if answer in word]` is never assigned to anything.